# Windows user command line permissions

Tags: command-line, permissions, php, user

My PHP service is started by SYSTEM user. But I couldn't execute this command on PHP:
http://localhost/execute.php file tries to execute this command:

```
D:\wamp\www\convert\OfficeToPDF.exe D:\wamp\www\convert\test.docx D:\wamp\www\convert\test.pdf
```

But when I am opened cmd window, then typed `php execute.php` it worked. How can I make PHP to execute this command when I am opening this link: http://localhost/execute.php

Comment: Were there any errors when the command failed to execute?

Comment: Do you have a web server installed?